# Loading Newtonsoft.Json.dll from app resource causing stack overflow

Tags: c#, .net-assembly

I am trying to load the `newtonsoft.json.dll` from the application resource like we did with all libraries for years now, but with the `newtonsoft.json.dll` i end up in an stack overflow exception because `Assembly.Load(data)` (data is byte[]) is causing `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve` to fire again asking for `newtonsoft.json.dll` did anyone ever expirienced something like this?

Comment: How did you get the `data (byte[])`? Is it `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(string)`?

Comment: Yes, and resource requests are handled correctly. I have recreated the resource cleaned the project and now as of sudden it works. I have no freaking idea what it was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to rebuilt the resource and clean the project manually in order to get it to work.